# How to import a vue component globally in a Nuxt 2 module?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Created a nuxt 2 module with the following contents:

```js
import type { Module } from '@nuxt/types'
// import { resolve } from 'path'

const sharedModule: Module = function () {
  const { nuxt } = this
  nuxt.hook('ready', (nxt: any) => {
    console.log('NUXT=====', nxt)
  })
}

export default sharedModule
```

I'm not using components auto-import, so i don't have "components:dirs" hook, because i cannot use it in my large project. How can i globally import my components during "ready" hook?

Comment: Just use `Vue.component(MyComponent)` to globally register the component.

Comment: @Kapcash won't work in a module

Comment: Yeah sorry, you actually have to provide a plugin from your module, which himself will globally register the components using `Vue.component()`.